# How to upload Zip file using servlet?

Tags: servlets, upload, netbeans-7, zip

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1.

Here i want to send the zip file from jsp file and get that zip file and store it to the local folder, is it possible.

I refer some pages like [Upload Zip File](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/apache-commons-fileupload-example-with-servlet-and-jsp)

in this page change the web.xml file, in my project don't have this web.xml file it's have only content.xml file.

How to solve this.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean I don't have web.xml? create one. Also web.xml is very important file for your web app configurations. put it in WEB-INF folder.